# Qt with python (pyside) rotation check fails

Tags: qt, rotation, pyqt, pyside

I have problem with rotation check with QGraphicsItemGroup. Several items are grouped into group which is rotating in scene. After rotation, the QGraphicsItem.rotation() always returns 0. The group is flagged with setHandlesChildEvents(False) - if it matters.

Furthermore, all child items are also rotated with group, and same method returns 0 for them as well (...maybe this is OK ).

Am I doing something wrong in checking group rotation ?

EDIT:

```
item_group.rotate(90)
print item_group.rotation() #prints 0
```

or

```
for i in item_group:
    i.rotate(90)
    print i.rotation() #also prints 0 for each
```

Comment: Pretty hard to tell without a code sample

Comment: Exactly. I'm also curious as to how exactly you're rotating

Comment: Here's code sample...THX